# Altura de un div con CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo un contenedor, si tiene bastante contenido aparecerá una barra de scroll, este a su vez tiene 3 divisiones.

El primero y último son de tamaño fijo, pero el central, tomará datos de una base, por lo que creará al principio 0 contenido (la altura de ese div será 0) luego según se metan datos, ese div irá creciendo, pero quiero que su altura máxima sea de 1000px, por ejemplo:

```css
.rowguardarcambios{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #B6BD99;
  }
  .colguardarcambios{
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #B6BD99;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
  }
  .alturaminimaymaxima{
    //
  }
```

```html
<!-- ALTURA FIJA -->
<div class="row rowguardarcambios">
    <div class="col s12 colguardarcambios">
        Altura fija
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ALTURA VARIABLE -->
<div class="row rowguardarcambios">
    <div class="col s12 colguardarcambios alturaminimaymaxima">
        Altura variable
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ALTURA FIJA -->
<div class="row rowguardarcambios">
    <div class="col s12 colguardarcambios">
        Altura fija
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Creo que este problema está resuelto en otro post. Te dejo el enlace por si te sirve. https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/418868/263200

Comment: Gracias, pero no es lo que necesito, eso se me había ocurrido pero no es lo que quiero que salga...
necesito que si no hay datos, ese div su altura sea 0, y si hay datos vaya creciendo (si hay 3 datos que ocupan 25px cada uno, pues que la altura sea 75) y si hay 100 datos que la altura maxima sea 100px y ya salga la barra de desplazamiento.

Comment: Vale ya lo he encontrado
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp
solo con poner max-height:500px y el overflow-y:auto, me funciona exactamente como queria.

Comment: solo con poner max-height:500px y el overflow-y:auto, me funciona exactamente como queria.

Comment: Perfecto me alegro de que hayas encontrado la respuesta

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.